# Text-alignment in css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align my text with left justify. What are the codes need to be added in css?

```
 <div class="traveldescription">Our experienced writers travel<br> the world to bring you informative and<br>inspirational features, destination<br>roundups,travel ideas, tips and beautiful<br>photos in order to help you<br>plan your next holiday.</div>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA1eW.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it inline like this:

```html
<div style="text-align: left;" class="traveldescription">Our experienced writers travel<br> the world to bring you informative and<br>inspirational features, destination<br>roundups,travel ideas, tips and beautiful<br>photos in order to help you<br>plan your next holiday.</div>
```

Or apply styles to your `traveldescription` class like this:

```css
.traveldescription {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="traveldescription">Our experienced writers travel<br> the world to bring you informative and<br>inspirational features, destination<br>roundups,travel ideas, tips and beautiful<br>photos in order to help you<br>plan your next holiday.</div>
```

Comment: How am I going to do if I want my text to be left-justify?